# Text-shadow отступ по оси х

Tags: css, text, photoshop

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Как из фотошопа вытащить параметры смещения тени по оси Х ? Там задается угол(Angle), и не совсем понятно как это все дело в px перевести. Возможно есть специальные формулы ? Гугл к сожалению не помог мне в этом вопросе.

Comment: загляните к дизайнеру с паяльником...

Comment: Вы бы не могли привести пример, как это делают нормальные дизайнеры ?)

Comment: пример не могу, но макет это еще не все. нормальный дизайнер готовит style guide где все размеры указаны.

Comment: да на самом деле, я только учусь. Верстаю бесплатный шаблон, по-этому было интересно узнать, как правильно вытаскивать тень из фотошопа.